# skip persisting entities if unique key matches

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Lets say thay I have an entity with name "A".It has two columns named as name and systemId.
These columns constraint unique key.For example it does not allow duplicate entities with systemId "1" and name "test".

My question is: I want to insert Collection of A entities.I want to skip duplicate entities just insert new ones.Is EntityManager able to skip these entities if unique constraint fails?
How can I succeed this?

Comment: If you haven't tried, as it seems, then try it & then if you encounter any issue, post a question with the relevant details/exceptions/code etc, someone will definitely help. EntityManager will throw exception *probably* without persisting & can ignore it in your case.

Comment: I tried and I know it throws exception.But I wonder if it can skip or merge without throwing exception

Comment: As previously said, update your post with relevant code. With proper exception handling, it could be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA does not allow for error handling, it requires that a transaction be marked for rollback if any error occurs.

You could insert each in a separate transaction, or put the whole transaction in a retry and reject the objects that fail on each pass.  You could also do a select first on the unique fields and skip the object if it already exists.